# custom styled component not behaving like div in flex wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, styled-components

I am using styled component to emulate behaviour of badges like in github, but even though I've set their container to `flex-wrap: wrap`, they dont wrap.

[image]

I added a div to see what's wrong but I dont see why it wouldn't wrap.

my css code:

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* min-width: 25vw; */
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.skills_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

my styled component:

```
const Skills = styled.div`
  border: solid 1px purple;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;
```

and my html:

```
      <div class={styles.skills_container}>
        <Skills color="limegreen"> Java </Skills>
        <Skills color="orange"> Python </Skills>
        <Skills color="limegreen"> JavaScript </Skills>
        <Skills color="limegreen"> Java </Skills>
        <Skills color="orange"> Python </Skills>
        <Skills color="limegreen"> JavaScript </Skills>
        <div>hello </div>
      </div>
```

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think there is enough space for them not to wrap.

Comment: @flvps oh you're right, that should've been my first clue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The  "hello" `div` wraps to the next line, so the flex items (which the DIV is a part of) *are*  wrapping. The `Skills` tags simply fit into on line, so they don't wrap befoere the "hello" div. Try to add some `paddng: left`/`padding-right` to the `Skills tab, then they will wrap at another position.